# Socket IO 1.x server library for python

Tags: python, socket.io, flask-socketio

is there any socket io 1.x server library for python? I have found https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO but only support for socket io version 0.9.16, this is the author say :

> Please do not use the new socket.io 1.0 client libraries, that is a
>   very recent release that is likely not supported by project
>   gevent-socketio. Please use 0.9.16 for now. https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/33

Please help me :)

Comment: The author of gevent-socketio does not have time to do the port to the 1.x version of the protocol. See https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio/issues/192.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.