# socket.io upgraded from 0.9.6 to 1.3.5 sends wrong requests

Tags: python, flask, websocket, socket.io, gevent-socketio

I had a small sandbox server on gevent-socketio.

The backend was

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from socketio import socketio_manage
from socketio.namespace import BaseNamespace
from socketio.server import SocketIOServer

class FirstNamespace(BaseNamespace):
    def on_make_upper_hook(self, msg):
        response = {'response from make_upper':msg.upper()}
        self.emit('response_channel', response)
        return True

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/socket.io/')
@app.route('/socket.io/<path:remaining>')
def socketio_endpoint(remaining=None):
    print('remaining path: {}'.format(remaining))
    socketio_manage(request.environ,
                    {'/chat': FirstNamespace})
    return 'ok'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SocketIOServer(('0.0.0.0', 8080), app,
        resource="socket.io").serve_forever()
```

And the frontend (with `socket.io 0.9.6`) was

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io.connect('/chat');
        socket.on('connect', function () {
            console.log('socket connected');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

In the browser console I saw that connection went fine. The server was also fine:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [2015-07-05 10:30:55] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 420 0.006791
remaining path: 1/websocket/683868734428
```

But!

When I tried to upgrade `socket.io` like so:

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.5.js"></script>
<script>

    var socket = io('http://localhost:8080/chat');
    socket.on('connect', function () {
        console.log('socket connected');
    });

</script>
```

I started to get client errors

```
GET http://localhost:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1436081649609-0 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

and server errors:

```
File "/Users/1111/.virtualenvs/stuff/lib/python2.7/site-packages/socketio/__init__.py", 
line 67, in socketio_manage
socket = environ['socketio']
KeyError: 'socketio'
```

So somehow my precious `socketio` key disappeared from `request.environ` and I don't know how to get it back. How to fix this?

Comment: so I see there's no way to fix this. `gevent-socketio` doesn't support newest `socketio` releases. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428273/socket-io-1-x-server-library-for-python